# Updating values in one table with values in another table in PySpark

Tags: sql, pyspark

Suppose I have the following two PySpark DataFrames:

DF1

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | null |
| 2 | b | e |

DF2

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | q |
| 2 | s | rr |

DESIRED OUTPUT:

| ID | VAL1 | VAL2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | z | a |
| 2 | b | e |

I would like to set the null value at ID = 1 in col VAL2 to a

Or more properly stated: Set DF1.VAL2 = DF2.VAL1 where DF1.id = DF2.id

I tried using sql update commands but am getting a mismatched input error.

Namely:

```
%sql
UPDATE DF1 set DF1.VAL2 = DF2.VAL1 FROM DF1 as DF1
INNER JOIN DF2 as DF2 ON DF1.ID = DF2.ID
```

Is this something that is doable in PySpark?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [coalesce](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.coalesce.html) with join.

`coalesce` will take first non-null value from columns.

First rename the

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = (df1.join(df2, on='ID').select(
    'ID',
    F.coalesce(df1.VAL1, df2.VAL1).alias('VAL1'),
    F.coalesce(df1.VAL2, df2.VAL1).alias('VAL2'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! This is giving me an Ambiguous error. Says "Please alias the Datasets with different names via 'Datasets.as' before joining them, and specify the column using qualified name, e.g., 'DF1.as("a").join(DF1.as("b"), $"a.ID" > $"b.ID")'

Comment: I tried adding aliases but that didn't work. Error persists. Added them to the DF's, the individual df columns in the coalesce functions etc. But still have the error.

Comment: Ah shoot ok I see the issue is due to DF2 being a filter of DF1. Didn't realize it would affect the example. My apologies.